# Javascript global variable undefined mobile safari Android works fine

Tags: javascript

Ok, so this has got me stumped, hoping one of you maybe can help me out. So, I have an app that is using capacitor to build. In my app I have global JS variables for example:

```
//globals 
var isCheckin = "";
var isUser = "";
```

etc...

On android, this works just fine (and previously, did work on IOS). But now, when I go to build it on IOS and run the application, my `if` statements for stuff like:

```
if(isCheckin !== "") {}
```

No longer work, because `isCheckin` is coming back as `undefined`.

I was doing some searching and came across 'hoisting' and while I guess that may be the case why would:

1. Android have no issue with the global?
2. IOS used to work, but now comes back as `undefined`?

In-fact, the current version of the app, in app store still works just fine, but new builds are having this issue when global variables seem to get ignored by safari.

Comment: Your question is kind of confusing without more code to support it well.  JavaScript global => not usually a good idea.

Comment: FWIW If you literally have `//globals var isCheckin = ""; var isUser = "";` you have a commented out code block.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of ***global** variable* should be defined.

Let's see this first example:

```js
const myFunction = (() => {
  var foo = 'bar';
});

myFunction();
console.log(foo);
```

The variable is getting defined in the scope of a function. I.e. outside that scope it will be undefined.

What you can do, is removing `var` from it. See:

```js
const myFunction = (() => {
  foo = 'bar';
});

myFunction();
console.log(foo);
```

Now the variable is global and can also be use outside the function. BUT if you set `"use stricht"`, the variable will be undefined. See:

```js
"use strict"
/* global console */


const myFunction = (() => {
  foo = 'bar';
});

myFunction();
console.log(foo);
```

So the cleanest way to get the value of the variable outside the scope is using `let`. See:

```js
"use strict"
/* global console */

let foo;
const myFunction = (() => {
  foo = 'bar';
});

myFunction();
console.log(foo);
```